# Excel VBA - Adding keys to duplicated couples

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a table in Excel with two columns with repeated values (text), and I need to create a new column (same sheet), where each (sorted) couple is associated with an integer.

Here a simplified example:

*--> Starting point*

[image]

*-->  Expected output*

[image]

Since the number of rows is really huge (**not known a priori** - data are imported from external files), I need to write the code in a very efficient way!

All suggestions are warmly welcomed!

Comment: Sounds like a well-defined question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks like you could just sort the first two columns, the third is a simple formula.

Comment: Automated with VBA: What you need is [Range.Sort Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) to sort the 2 columns and a [loop](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures) going through the rows and compare the current row with the row above. If it's the same then write the same *unit* if it's different then write the *unit + 1*. Manual version: see comment above.

Comment: do they have to start at 1 and increment?  `MATCH` would help if not, you'd get 1,1,3,3,3,6 instead

Comment: I like SJR's answer.  Except it sounds like you want to add the integer key before the sort, that is to say if the goal is to retain the original order.  Add the key column and populate it with 1 through whatever the last used row is.  Then sort on any column in the three.  You can always return to original order by sorting on the index key column.  But if the goal is to put duplicates in order then SJR's advice is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Manual method

1. Manually sort the columns
2. Insert `1` into cell C1
3. Insert `=IF(AND(A2=A1,B2=B1),C1,C1+1)` into cell C2 and copy this cell down.

---

#### VBA method (via macro recorder)

1. Start recording a macro
2. Manually do all 3 steps from above (manual method)
3. Stop macro recording

Now you have a basic macro that you can modify to your needs and learn from.